# svn log not working recursively

Tags: svn

I commited a file this morning using the following command:

```
svn commit -m "some text" pg1ch/mobile/index_2_pg1app_r2.php
```

Then later I tried the command from the root of the svn directory:

```
svn log
```

This would now show the revision I had just commited.  To actually see the revision I had to use:

```
svn log pg1ch/mobile/index_2_pg1app_r2.php
```

Why do I need to put the full file of that path to see the revision?  Even using the following commands would not display it:

```
svn log pg1ch/
svn log pg1ch/mobile/
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `svn update` at the top level after committing the single file at a deeper directory. Without doing so, you have a mixed-revision working copy and the top level (where you're running svn log) isn't seeing that latest revision number.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `svn log --full` to get all logs, If there is so many log then it won't be a good idea to see last logs. Instead of the you can use `svn log --limit 10` to see last 10 logs.